# making a book cover by Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

A way I make a book cover with TikZ is getting 4 coordinates of the cover page (book), then freely drawing inside ABCD with TikZ commands.

Can we do similar for Asymptote, that is, getting 4 coordinates of the cover page and use them in Asymptote code?

For example below, the picture and last TikZ code of the cover page I redraw. I have tried something with Asymptote, but it did not work as expected.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(current page.north west); 
pair B=(current page.north east);
pair C=(current page.south east);
pair D=(current page.south west);
pair E=(current page.center);

draw(A--C,blue);
draw(B--D,red);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

PS: Well, the reasson I look for Asymptote way is: Even in 2D, Asymptote is somehow better than TikZ, for example, in drawing graph of Implicit function. I want to utilise excellent capability of Asymptote.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{denim}{rgb}{0.08, 0.38, 0.74}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path 
(current page.north west) coordinate (A) 
(current page.north east) coordinate (B)
(current page.south east) coordinate (C)
(current page.south west) coordinate (D)
(current page.center) coordinate (E);
% Now you have book cover as the rectangle ABCD
% You are free to draw inside ABCD

\fill[denim] (A) rectangle (C);
\draw[white,line width=1.5mm] 
([shift={(6,0)}]A)--([shift={(6,0)}]D)
([shift={(6.25,0)}]A)--([shift={(6.25,0)}]D);

\node[white,scale=1.5,align=left,
font=\bfseries\sffamily] at ([shift={(2.5,-3)}]A) 
{Stability\\ 
and Control:\\
Theory,\\
Method and\\
Applications\\
Volume 15};

\node[white,xscale=5,yscale=5,align=left,
font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([shift={(2.5,4.5)}]E) 
{Almost Periodic\\ 
Solutions of \\
Differential\\
Equations in\\
Banach Spaces};

\node[white,scale=2,align=left,
font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([shift={(1,-5)}]E) 
{Y. Hino, T. Naito,\\ 
Nguyen Van Minh\\
and Jong Son Shin};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: when you already make a title page with Ti*k*Z, why do you want to switch to Asymptote?

Comment: @ JouleV: Even in 2D, Asymptote is better than TikZ, for example, in drawing graph of Implicit function,...

Comment: I did not say that Asymptote is bad. But you can always use Ti*k*Z in the title page and Asymptote in the document :)) I think it is not really necessary to use only one graphics tool throughout the document.

Comment: @ JouleV: I agree that TikZ is excellent! TikZ can draw Cassini curves, but not very well, not good quality (through GNU). In case using Cassini curves for book cover, we should use Asymptote.

Comment: I agree. However, for example if I already had my title page drawn in PSTricks, I would not redraw it in Ti*k*Z, but in the main document I still use Ti*k*Z. What I mean is that, there is no need to redraw the title page using another tool, when you already have the page drawn in some other tools. I agree that Asymptote is better than Ti*k*Z at some points, and vice versa, but in this particular case, they are equal IMHO. Anyway it is only my own humble opinion :))

Comment: @ JouleV: Okay, I've just edit my question. I am asking how to get 4 coordinates of the cover page and use them in Asymptote code. The picture and TikZ code are just for illustrating as example

Comment: @BlackMild Please don't advise me using Asymptote.

Comment: @ minh thiện: No, I don’t. 3D is only for very hình and special needs

Comment: I agree with @JouleV that you can use asymptote and Ti*k*Z in the same document. After all the fonts are all generated with LaTeX and in the cover I do not see any element such as an arrow head which could tell them apart. And I really think that for such simple things as the cover Ti*k*Z is simpler to use, but of course I agree that there are things that you can do easily with asymptote but require major efforts with Ti*k*Z.

Comment: If you can save the page coordinates to macros (say, `\myAsyCoordA`, `\myAsyCoordB`, etc), then these macros will be visible **if you use `asypictureB`** in your asymptote code as `@myAsyCoordA`, `@myAsyCoordB`, etc. But in general I think Ti*k*Z is a better choice for drawing directly on the page; `asymptote` uses `graphicx` internally to import images, so it's mostly suited to drawing independent graphics rather than interacting with TeX elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was convoluted to start and took much trial and error to get a simplified result but here you are.

P.S.  needs 2 x pdfLaTeX , 1 x Asy , another 2 x pdfLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{denim}{rgb}{0.08, 0.38, 0.74}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path 
(current page.north west) coordinate (A) 
(current page.north east) coordinate (B)
(current page.south east) coordinate (C)
(current page.south west) coordinate (D)
(current page.center) coordinate (E);
% Now you have book cover as the rectangle ABCD
% You are free to draw inside ABCD
\fill[denim] (A) rectangle (C);
\draw[white,line width=1.5mm] 
([shift={(6,0)}]A)--([shift={(6,0)}]D)
([shift={(6.25,0)}]A)--([shift={(6.25,0)}]D);

\node[white,scale=1.5,align=left,
font=\bfseries\sffamily] at ([shift={(2.5,-3)}]A) 
{Stability\\ 
and Control:\\
Theory,\\
Method and\\
Applications\\
Volume 15};

\node[white,xscale=5,yscale=5,align=left,
font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([shift={(2.5,4.5)}]E) 
{Almost Periodic\\ 
Solutions of \\
Differential\\
Equations in\\
Banach Spaces};
\node[white,scale=2,align=left,
font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ([shift={(1,-5)}]E) 
{Y. Hino, T. Naito,\\ 
Nguyen Van Minh\\
and Jong Son Shin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}[width=\the\linewidth,inline=true]
pair A=(0,1.2);
pair B=(1,1.2);
pair C=(1,0);
pair D=(0,0);
draw(A--C,N,blue,Arrows);
dot(D,red+0.15cm);
label("$BL$",D,1.5N,red);
label("$TR$",B,1.5N,red);
draw(B--D,N,red,Arrows);
\end{asy}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, KJO! I wonder i am the only one voted so far

Comment: Possibly I'm the only one other than you with a download :-) P.S forgot to mention the units are relative and arbitrary as I tested so 10 wide x 12 high should work same as 50 x 60 etc. may be able to squeeze 50 x say 62 but there is a point at which it tips into next page